# experimental verification of theory

Tags: experimental-physics

Which equation of physics could we call the best verified one experimentally? Let us define "best verified" in the sense of smallest relative error of the predicted variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is the [gyromagnetic ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio#Gyromagnetic_ratio_for_an_isolated_electron) of an electron. This makes [quantum electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) the most accurate theory.

Comment: Thank you for that factoid.  That's one for the front burner, for those of us who don't believe the universe is a bunch of different worlds, where anything goes in the way of local rules and laws, and they are all tied together with tiny "strings" which somehow can wiggle, and hence must be made of components, even smaller and more fundamental.    Now does QCD supplant QED, or is it still QED that rules the roost?   Thanks again.